# type 'NodeListOf<HTMLLIElement>' is not assignable to type 'Element[]'

Tags: javascript, typescript

> let li: Element[] = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

I get the type conversion error, how to store the values in  **'Element[ ]'** ??

Comment: I assume it's an array, so you use `push()`?

Comment: can you suggest alternate method?? @Mr.Alien

Answer (score 6):

The object returned from `document.getElementsByTagName('span')` is not compatible with an array object. You need to declare it as following:

```
let li: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

If you really need this to be an array object you can use:

```
let li: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
let liArray: Element[] = Array.prototype.slice.call(li);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like object, not an actual array. You need to coerce it to one first using the spread operator (or `[].slice.call(...)` for ES5):

```
let li: HTMLElement[] = [...document.getElementsByTagName('span')]
```

Comment: Another way: `let li: HTMLElement[] = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the implicit form of the variable first, then transfer this definition explicitly:

```
let li = document.getElementsByTagName('span');//Hover IDE
```

To..

```
let li: NodeListOf<HTMLSpanElement>= document.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

Then..

```
let arr: Element[]
    for (let i in li) 
      arr.push(li[i] as Element)
```