# TypeScript set css style for HTMLCollectionOf<Element>, NodeCollection<Element>,google autocomplete forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

how I can set css style for HTMLCollectionOf or NodeCollection

```
 let items = document.querySelectorAll('.pac-item') as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
```

[image]

For HTMLElement set style working good
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943071/type-nodelistofhtmllielement-is-not-assignable-to-type-element/42943582#42943582

Comment: You cant. Iterate over it and assign it to each element :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank's guys!
My fail...that was collection of elements...resolved it by itteration

```
 var items:any = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-item');
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            let element = items[i];
            element.style.background = '#2B2B2B';
            element.style.color = '#DEDEDE';
        }
```

Comment: This generates a TypeScript error for me that 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.  The code works if you simply ignore the compiler error, but if you want to make it go away, you need to use `document.getElementsByClassName('pac-item') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>`

Answer (score 3):

The typescript definition suggests that `HTMLCollectionOf` is an extension of HTMLCollection and you need to iterate over it to access individual elements.

```
interface HTMLCollectionOf<T extends Element> extends HTMLCollection {
    item(index: number): T;
    namedItem(name: string): T;
    [index: number]: T;
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `HtmlCollectionOf`, so it is a collection and a collection has many items. Therefore `items.style.background` does not work because it belongs to `HtmlElement`.

In other words, you'll have to loop over the collection to apply to each of the `HtmlElement`. Or you can apply to specific one like below, which I think is what you're trying to do

`items[0].style.background = '#2B2B2B';`