# TypeScript and React JS Access The DOM Element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code here, it says, `elements[i].style` does not exist, any idea why?

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("contentHeaderTitleField");
for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].textContent == '') {
        elements[i].style
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of elements are the ones you are selecting?

Comment: What is the aim of your loop? Currently it just iterates through elements, and tries to access the style of an element, if its `textContent` is "". It does not do anything though!

Comment: Style does not exist on all DOM [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). Only on [HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) a selector is not guaranteed to only match HTML elements. If you are 100% certain that it did you can do `(elements[i] as HTMLElement).style`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript set css style for HTMLCollectionOf<Element>, NodeCollection<Element>,google autocomplete forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093614/typescript-set-css-style-for-htmlcollectionofelement-nodecollectionelement)

Comment: @Chris, it a div

Comment: @apokryfos, you are correct,i can directly cast the object to strong type object...

Comment: elements[i] is of type DOM.Element and has therefore no property `style`. Not every Element is an HtmlElement.

Comment: try using `document.querySelectorAll('.contentHeaderTitleField')` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, method **getElementsByClassName** returns `HTMLCollectionOf<Element>`,
and **Element** interface doesn't have 'style' property, so you should, for example, cast the return type to collection of HTML elements, like this:

`let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("contentHeaderTitleField") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>`